# Change Eclipse RCP unknown file type association programmatically

Tags: eclipse-rcp, file-association

I am building a 3.x RCP application and I add some Eclipse based default features such as Project Explorer, toolbars, preferences pages etc.

My problem is when I drag and drop a file that is not associated with any editor. In that case Eclipse RCP uses the default editor that my OS uses. I know I can change it from *Preferences* > *Editors*, but I would like to change the default value of that preferences by coding.

I want to assign unknown file types to the Eclipse text editor. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no such preference page as 'Preferences > Editors' - exactly what preference do you want to change?

Comment: Preferences: General>Editors>File Associations>Open unassociated files with: System editor. I want its default value to be internal text editor @greg-449

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'Preferences > General > Editors > File Associations > Open unassociated files with' ends up setting the `IDE.UNASSOCIATED_EDITOR_STRATEGY_PREFERENCE_KEY` preference key in the preference store for the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in. The value of the key for using the text exitor is `org.eclipse.ui.ide.textEditor`

So you should be able to use something like:

```java
IPreferenceStoere store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, ""org.eclipse.ui.ide"");

store.setValue(IDE.UNASSOCIATED_EDITOR_STRATEGY_PREFERENCE_KEY,
               "org.eclipse.ui.ide.textEditor");
```

Comment: which extension point should I use for it? Since it is eclipse based preferences I don't have the control of that preferences page.